# Create dynamic forms

Tags: php, javascript, html

Up to this point I've avoided javascript, mostly because I'm a newbie.  But I think I can't avoid it anymore?

I have a simple form in a table that I process with php.

```
<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Quality</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>IP</td>
        <td>Port</td>
        <td>Options</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="text" size="18" maxlength="32" name="add_name" value="Enter name" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <select name="add_quality">
                <option value='HIGH' selected='selected'>High</option>
                <option value='MEDIUM'>Medium</option>
                <option value='MOBILE'>Mobile</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <select name="add_status">
                <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>Enabled</option>
                <option value='DISABLED'>Disabled</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="14" maxlength="16" name="add_user" value="Enter username" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" size="12" maxlength="16" name="add_pass" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="16" name="add_ip" value="Enter IP" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="6" name="add_port" value="Enter Port #" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
            </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    </form>
</table>
```

I'd like to take this table and only keep the first three input types shown (Name, Quality, Status).  The rest would open up if you hit a "details" link or button.  So the table would expand (or ideally go to the next line as this table is too long).  That details button or link would have to toggle on and off.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't have a form inside a table and outside of a table (data or header) cell. Error recover variations between browsers **will** cause breakage.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean?

Comment: Your `<form>` wraps around the `<tbody>` element, but is also inside of `<table>`. Move the form tags outside of the `<table>` element. @Quentin says that different browsers will handle this differently, so don't expect it to work in all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic javascript approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display === 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Then place a button or link with:

```
<input type="button" value="Details" onClick="toggle_visibility('detailsWrapper')">
```

Finally, just make a div or maybe a new tr around the fields you want to hide with the id set to "detailsWrapper" and style it with display:none.

Alternatively you can use this function:

```
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var control = document.getElementById(controlId);
           if(control.style.visibility == "visible" || control.style.visibility == "")
              control.style.visibility = "hidden";
           else 
              control.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
```

If I remember correctly this will reserve the needed space to display the element, so it won't mess up your layout.

Comment: `language=` is depreciated. Use `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: This works on the most part, but the tables get messed up no matter how I play around with it.  I'll keep trying...

Comment: It shouldn't mess up layout too much if you use:                </select></td></tr><tr id='detailsWrapper' style='display:none;'>
<td>                                                                      Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: It isn't too bad but I want to keep the header of the table.  I think I got it now but just creating a separate table.  Seems to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For animations, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is my favorite JavaScript library. It makes things quite a lot easier.

This code might work for you:

```
$('#my-table tr td').each(function(i) {
  if (i >= 3) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});

$('#details').click(function() {
  $('#my-table tr td').each(function(i) {
    if (i >= 3) {
      $(this).slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow that does seem simple. I was avoiding javascript (and jquery) altogether, but maybe I should rethink that.

Comment: How else are you going to animate it? You will have to use clientside scripting, and JavaScript is the only language that is supported by every browser (normal) people use.

Comment: I can hope? Yes I knew javascript would be part of this I mean I've just been avoiding it up till now.  What I need to rethink is jquery.  I have tons of problems with jquery on my Joomla site...so far I'm staying away.

Comment: The only problem you can have is not including it. Good luck not using it for animations, though ;)